# execute procedure having grant statements from BODS

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, user-roles, sql-grant, sap-data-services

I have a procedure that runs `grant select` statements for various tables in different schema . I have used `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` for this to execute successfully from SQL Developer.

But when I try to execute the same procedure from [BODS designer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap_bods/sap_bods_ds_designer_introduction.htm), it shows me the same error that I was getting before I used`AUTHID CURRENT_USER` when executing from SQL Developer

> Oracle DNZ.WORLD error message for operation OCIStmtExecute:
>   ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from

So is there a way to execute a procedure with `grant` statements in it , from BODS designer?

Comment: Can you post more details? Your procedure grants select for various tables to which user? I'm not aware how BODS Designer works but when you are using `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` which means if the schema being used by BODS Designer does not have GRANT privileges you cannot GRANT.

Comment: @Arijit  thanks for the quick reply but sorry , i cant post the code . can you tell me how to execute a grant select statement from BODS , and what all access and roles the user should have have

Comment: You can post example code which doesn't anything like your actual code. Use table/schema names like Table_A, Table_B etc. We need to know which schema you are trying to grant to before we can help you.

Comment: created a procedure in Schema A , which grants select to table B in schema B . now when i execute the procedure directly in Schema A , it works , but when i am calling it through bods , it shows above mentioned error .

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the schema being used by BODS Designer does not have privileges to grant select on another schema's objects. Using `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` causes Oracle to run the procedure with the privileges of BODS Designer which may not have the GRANT option.
Removing the `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` will run the procedure with the privileges of the schema which defines the procedure and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Removing AUTHID CURRENT_USER will show error as schema A doenot not have privilage to grant select to table in schema B

Comment: Is Schema A the one you are logging into from SQL Developer?

Comment: I am logging into the database , which has 9 different schemas . To access any table there we access it as SchemaName.TableName without any problems . Only when accessing cross schema from procedure without AUTHID and from BODS , it shows errors

Comment: Right but which schema are you logging into? 
It looks like the schema you are logging into has a privilege to grant but the BODS schema does not.